# How to combine relationships on normalized json with lodash?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, lodash, ngrx

So what I have is two arrays of objects, one with people and the other with jobs like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Daniel',
    job: 146
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jose',
    job: 163
  }
]
```

and:

```
[
  {
    id: 146,
    name: 'Developer'
  },
  {
    id: 163,
    name: 'DevOps'
  }
]
```

I want to obtain a single array of people where the job id is replaced with the whole job object itself, like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Daniel',
    job: {
      id: 146,
      name: 'Developer'
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jose',
    job: {
      id: 163,
      name: 'DevOps'
    }
  }
]
```

Maybe lodash is not the best approach, but I have no other idea. Help if you can and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var persons=[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Daniel',
    job: 146
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jose',
    job: 163
  }
];

var jobs=[
  {
    id: 146,
    name: 'Developer'
  },
  {
    id: 163,
    name: 'DevOps'
  }
];

var retVal=persons.map(p=>{
return {...p,job:jobs.find(j=> j.id==p.job)};
})

console.log(retVal)
```

Comment: your approach is the most easy to read and quickly understand as compare to @Nick Parsons pruposal. But the counter part is the algorithm complexity.

Comment: @Yanis-git i don't think op is going to load thousands of record at once from api and as it runs on ui side this should be negligible effect on performance

Comment: yes definitely, impact can be filled only from millions of composition. Just want to share this information in case someone who read this plan to have this constraint. Thanks for your sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can create a look-up-table (ie: object) from your array of jobs using `.reduce()` where the job's id becomes the key and the job itself becomes the value. You can then `.map()` your people array to include the `job` value from the look-up-table you previously created.

See example below:

```js
const people = [{id:1,name:"Daniel",job:146},{id:2,name:"Jose",job:163}];
const jobs = [{id:146,name:"Developer"},{id:163,name:"DevOps"}];

const lut = jobs.reduce((acc, job) => (acc[job.id] = job, acc), {});
const result = people.map(({job, ...person}) => ({...person, job: lut[job]}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```